# How to send custom request or response headers to APM from Keycloak Integration Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, multi-tenant, apm

I'm working on springboot project and we are using openId keycloak for authentication. I'm delaing with Multitenancy concept too. I want to sent custom header as request or either response and the same should be captured in APM as metadata. My current approach is as follows:

---

```
public class PreAuthFilter extends KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter {

@Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("X-Realm",realm);
super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
}
```

---

### But with above code i'm getting multiple response metatdata in APM

```
http.response.headers.X-Realm.0

http.response.headers.X-Realm.1

http.response.headers.X-Realm.2
```

### http.response.headers.X-Realm.3

### My expectation was single realm in APM Metadata

```
http.response.headers.X-Realm = "value"
```

---

I think SimpleHttpFacade is getting intialized during resolving deployment multiple times hence adding the response.

Need Suggestion

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this could be that the issue is more likely related to your application context spring and filters.

Since it's spring could you try `OncePerRequestFilter` ?

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

@Named
public class ApmFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // do apm things

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```